# Documentation for python base classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This has got to be a silly question... but googling didn't actually help. Extra kudos for pycharm enabled answers. :)

I need a simple little UDP echo server (spare me the twisted advertisements please, this is a throw away thing, I just need to use it to peek at what a little embedded gadget is broadcasting). So I find [section 21.21 of the Python 3 reference manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html?highlight=udp#socketserver-udpserver-example). It's a simple example that does exactly what I want.

But the same document also mentions a `DatagramRequestHandler` class. But there's no further explanation on how that differs from its parent class, or what it provides. I had really hoped that when I imported said class, that pycharm would somehow display a helpful popup for it, but I'm unable to discover such a thing.

Do I assume correctly, that I should just go find the source in my (macosx) install and look directly at that? is there a pattern for how people do that? My actual question here, is actually less about DatagramRequestHandler, and more about the general pattern, because this obviously will happen else where in the base docs.

(context: my traditional experience is with Smalltalk image based environments, where you can always just jump from class to class to class, and navigate quickly from application code all the way to the bowels, as a sort of exploratory way of learning and discovery)

Comment: have you tried Navigate->Declaration (Ctrl-b in my keyboard layout)?

Comment: THAT is exactly what I was looking for. Doesn't show up in editor context menu. You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to navigate to the declaration of the name under your cursor, Navigate->Declaration (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> in my keymap).

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a question there are three things to do:

1. google it (eg. `python DatagramRequestHandler`)
2. use the `help` function in a interactive python session. eg.

   ```
   import socketserver; help(socketserver.DatagramRequestHandler)
   ```
3. look into the code

Most of the time the first option is enough (this time I found only something in german). The result from the second option is in this "example" not so interesting or useful. So you have to use try third option.

Comment: Option 2 was helpful! Thanks!